# How do I retrieve tickets for a specific month?

Tags: zendesk-api

I would like to retrieve data on tickets for the month of July. I used the incremental export to set the "start_time" to July 1st but I am also receiving tickets for August as well.

I noticed that Zendesk has "end_time" but I don't know how or if it is possible to use both start time and end time together to limit my data only to July. I'm using Python to do this.

[Link](https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/incremental/tickets.json?start_time=1561939200)

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on zendesk api in python but I want to tell you that there is "start_time" in ***ticket*** api here you can see that [link](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/tickets).

Yeah there is "start_time" in Zendesk Talk api in ***Incremental Export***, and here it is working absolutely fine.